# Как добавить символ

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Есть такой код:

```
$comments_day= $row['count'] ? $row['count'] : '';
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, как сюда `$comments_day= **$row['count']** ? $row['count'] : '';` добавить знак `+ ?`, чтобы на сайте выводился знак `+` и число (`+8`, например).

**Обновление**

Вроде как `$row['count']` - это уже число.

Точнее тут идет условие, как я понял:

```
$comments_day= $row['count'] ? $row['count'] : '';
create_cache("comments_day", $comments_day);
```

Если у нас `$comments_day = 0`, то 0 не показывает. Если же `$comments_day>0`, то выводит это `$comments_day`.

Вот как добавить такое: если `$comments_day>0`, то выводить + `$comments_day`?

Comment: оператор конкатенации - точка:

    $row['count'] . '+' . $number

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$comments_day = $row['count'] ? '+'.$row['count'] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще лучше сделать так:

```
sprintf("%+d",$row['count']);
```

А пока Вы будете прибегать к подобным махинациям, как одновременное хранение числового и строкового значения в одной переменной, хорошего ничего не будет. Лучше храните значение `0` и пишите, опираясь на это. Если используете какой-либо шаблон, например, Вам же будет проще - запишите условие в шаблон.

```
//Какой то абстрактный шаблонизатор
{if $comments_day > 0}
   {$comments_day}
{endif}
```

Куда лучше, чем

```
{$comments_day}
```

а потом искать, почему не выводится.